# How to put an intuitive system for my discord bot when typing its command / in the discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

how can I make in javascript to have when I type the command of my bot in my discord the help like in the picture with the logo of my bot and all the possible commands please?
Thank you to all.

[image: 1]

I have tested with discord.js but I can't find anything about it... I have tried with switch but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you see in the picture are called application commands (also known as slash commands). They are not the same as prefix commands (ex: `!help`). You can check the full guide on how to construct these type commands [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#before-you-continue).

Application/slash commands are highly recommended as they provide more features and are generally easier to handle over prefix commands.

If you already have slash commands set up, you can check the guide on how to register them [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration). If you register your commands they will pop up in the image you linked.